# Auto publish file on save - Eclipse IDE

Tags: css, eclipse, sass, aptana

I'm Running Aptana/Eclipse with a project set to publish to a (UNIX) remote server on save. All good. But I also have Compass compiling my scss files into a singular CSS file. Now the issue is that on save it only publishes/pushes the file that has been saved (The SCCS File), Not the CSS file. Is there a way to publish all changed files, or anything similar?

**Development on**: Windows 7 + Ruby, Compass, Eclipse

**Server** : Linux Ubuntu

Comment: How do you save the files on the remote server?

Comment: The files are uploaded via SFTP , using Eclipse , Ive previously accessed my server via the "Remote Server" Tab . But now i work via the project explorer where each project is linked to the server. I also have builders on each project for compass to compile.